# "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when installing lshash

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I'm getting

```
"python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

when doing `pip install lshash` on Google Colab.

See the following notebook 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F-4jtJ7WaItojjUcP1RnFrMW4tQvPIc-

I tried installing the dependencies of the lshash package [listed on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/lshash/).

```
!pip install bitarray
!pip install redis
!pip install lshash
```

No use.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your notebook and knowing that you were using Python3. In python3 you may install lshash by

> pip3 install lshash3

If you successfully install lshash and still getting an `No module future` error, just

> pip3 install future

Hope it will help!